# What is the best way to manage server redirect obtained under Angular translate JSON loading?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, redirect, internationalization, angular-translate

We are using AWS cloudfront to store our translation locale JSON files. Our Angular application gets these files via StaticFilesLoader in angular translate module.

In most cases it works perfectly. However after an environment is freshly created AWS could responses redirect to other location to get translation files. It is normal cloudfront behavior. But StaticFilesLoader is not able to follow this redirect and crashes with error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://some.cloudfront.net/3...9-a...0-1..c-9...f/i18n/locale-en.json. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Is there any known solution of this issue? Could you please give me some suggestion how to solve it?

A workaround could be to write interceptor to catch the redirect and fetch data with provided URL. But I decided to ask community before.

Comment: See [AngularJS Issue ##14491 Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14491). Writing an interceptor won't work, redirects are handled (and rejected) by the browser. The AngularJS framework is not involved.